# Apply an index command on a matrix of lists

Tags: r, list, subset, apply, igraph

I have a matrix that contains lists containing shortest path sequences of an `igraph object`.
I want to turn this matrix into an `igraph.es`(edge sequence).

sample:

```
library(igraph)
data <- data.frame(from  =c(1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1),
                   to    =c(4,  3,  4,  5,  6,  5),
                   weight=c(0.2,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.2))

g <- graph.data.frame(data, directed=FALSE)


sp <- sapply(data, function(x){shortest_paths(g, from = x, to = V(g)[x],output = "epath")})
```

`sp` is now a matrix. We can subset it with indexing:

```
x<-sp[[2]][[2]]
```

will turn `x` to an `igraph::edge_sequence`.

I'm looking for an `apply` command to turn all path_sequences of `sp` into `edge_sequences`. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I managed to unlist the first layer of the list.

```
sp<-flatten(sp)
```

So we just need a simple index.

Can I just use a `for loop` now?
Something like:

```
for(i in sp){ result[i]<- sum(E(g)$weight[sp[[i]])}
```

unfortunately this doesn't give me the desired output..

Comment: Could you please explain which shortest paths you are trying to compute? When you run `sapply` on `data` you are looping through the columns. So for instance when `x` is the weight column within the loop to create `sp`, `V(g)[x]` does not make any sense.

Comment: I try to compute the shortest from the ``from`` column to the ``to`` column.
In my "real" problem. I built ``data`` from the ``igraph::shortest.paths`` matrix.